# How to create multiple copies of form fields dynamically in extjs?

Tags: templates, extjs, dynamically-generated

I want to be able to ask a user to specify how many unique entries they wish to enter, then dynamically generate that number of identical fieldsets, each with same form fields, e.g Name, Size, Colour, etc; basically having the fieldset as a template of sorts.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom fieldset and add it to form panel, one way of doing that : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2c5